# iOS standard location service vs significant-change location service vs region monitoring

Tags: ios, gps, location, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am developing an iOS app whose one of its main functionalities is listening for the user's location. I need a high location accuracy to be aware of when the user gets inside certain areas, and I am not sure what kind of location service should I use.

AFAIK, *significant-change location service* provides low accuracy, right? I do not know exactly what should understand by "significant-change". I have not read about its accuracy in Apple's docs, but I read something about it in some posts, so this won't fit my needs. If it is that way, I should choose between *standard location service* and *region monitoring*. I know that the standard service can be set an accuracy level and a distance filter, but this seems to drain the battery. On the other hand, region monitoring seems to be more efficient in terms of power level, but I am not sure if I can reach high accuracy with this service. And I need to monitor a lot of areas; I don't know if that is possible or it can only be provided one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AFAIK, significant-change location service provides low accuracy,
>   right?

yes, forget it for your high location accuracy demand.
Either you are satisified with about (some) hundred meters to some kilometers cell Tower locating, or you need some meter (3-30m) acuuracy(GPS).
Inbetween nothing, sometimes only Wifi, which works only in cities.

> If it is that way, I should choose between standard location service
>   and region monitoring.

For high accuracy you would need standard location service with `desiredAccuracy` Best

To battery drainage: 
I the device is not used otherwise, I can run it 8h in fulll GPS quality mode.
So the user should have an active benefitr of your application. like navigation.

Answer (score 3):

there is always a war between compromising battery over getting accurate location.
it totally depends upon your app's requirement and user's preference.

As a user I want this choice rather than a "forced feature" and hence I think you can provide both approaches and let use choose between "accuracy" and "battery life".

If you can provide this choice to the end user then you must not keep it with you.

I hope this clarifies my view.

like they use to say in Matrix - "You do have a choice!!"